# How can I disable the Samsung Galaxy s4 standard calendar?

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-4

[image: calendar screenshot]

Please help. I've spent several hours on this and cannot figure it out. I see that the best answer to this issue is to go to the menu and change settings. If you see the screenshot, there is no menu option as far as I can tell. I have tried using the hidden menu button. Am I missing something?

I have also tried to disable the app in the app manager menu and continue getting double notifications. Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Using ADB shell PM HIDE command you should be able to disable this app. May I ask why you want to disable it?

Comment: I am using the Google calendar app which I like much better but then it gives me double notifications for every event. In any case, where would I find the menu in that app based off the screenshot?

Comment: There's no menu, you can bring the menu by touching the menu key/button

Answer (score 0):

You can try deleting all data and cache related to the calendar app.

Go to Settings > Apps > All apps > Touch the app for which you want to clear data > Clear data

**For disabling** :

- Activate USB Debugging in Settings > Developers Options. If you can't find it, go to Settings > About device > Tap 7 times to bring the Developers Options.
- Download Debloater from [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software/debloater-remove-carrier-bloat-t2998294) and install it
- Connect the phone to the computer (need [Samsung USB drivers](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads) installed)
- Open Debloater, click on READ DEVICE PACKAGES
- Find and select the email package (read carefully)
- Click on block. Now the app will not be longer available.